# How do you post content to a static wordpress page, using xmlrpc in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am struggling to understand how it is possible to add content to static pages on the WordPress site.  Surely there is a way to do this?

I have read the Python documentation regarding making posts to a WordPress site via the python-wordpress-xmlrpc package.  I can make automated posts from a Python script to the posts page as per the example here:

https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/posts.html

More specifically, I have an automated script to upload media to the media folder for the WordPress site, as per the example here:

https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/media.htm

Then I want to add a link to that specific media on one of the existing static pages on the WordPress site.

I hope that is clear.  If you need any more information, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like there two different things, and the distinction between them has gotten blurred. First, there is actual content that the WordPress site knows about; second, there's other (static) content that just happens to be in the same site as the WordPress content is, and which, for the most part, WordPress knows nothing about. I assume that the `python-wordpress-xmlrpc` package can help with the former, but you need help with the latter, which doesn't have much to with WordPress per so.

Comment: ... The one exception which kinda straddles the border is fixed content uploaded by content creators, and attached to content. (Typically it's images associated with blog posts.) Re-reading your question, I see that's kinda what you're aiming at. You might be able to use what you have to upload things, but I'm not sure what you mean by a 'static' page. If a WordPress page had something in it to show all its attached content (so it isn't really static), you could upload something, associate it with that page, and WordPress would display it. Is that what you're aiming for?